# Swift/iOS storing the encryption key best pratice

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Does anyone have suggestions/best practice to store the encryption key(s) for iPhone apps?

Also with Firebase remote config feature, has anyone implemented that in their project in order to change the keys if needed/required?!

Comment: Do you mean in your development environment, or in the application?

Comment: Firebase remote config is not a solution for providing keys to an app. From the documentation: "Don't store confidential data in Remote Config parameter keys or parameter values. It is possible to decode any parameter keys or values stored in the Remote Config settings for your project". There is no truly secure way of storing keys that need to ship with an app. You can obscure them through various techniques but thi sonny makes it harder for an attacker. It doesn't prevent key extraction

Comment: Use the iOS Keychain, you can not do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing your key(s) use
[keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW3,).
As the documentation says:

> Keychain Services provides secure storage of passwords, keys, certificates, and notes for one or more users.

You can also use a simple Swift wrapper - [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess)